# What term describes parsing code (c#) to trace references?

Tags: c#, parsing, reference

I want to trace C# code, and I'm not sure of the technical terminology to Google the approach.

Pretend I want to understand which parts of my code depend upon a stored procedure.

Pseudo-code:

- FIND the proc name in visual studio, and get result(s).
- for each result, identify the entity (constant or method) the result occurs in.
- for each entity, follow references (recursively) to tail.

Example:

- FIND "UpsertFoo_spr" (result: string)
- String exists in "FooRepository.Save()"
- "FooRepository.Save()" is called by "FooController.SaveFoo()" and "FooController.ReassignFoo()"
- "FooController.SaveFoo()" is called by "[FooDetails.aspx].Save_OnClick()"
- "FooController.ReassignFoo()" is called by "[FooManager.aspx].Reassign_OnClick()"

If you can just tell me what this is called, I can Google solutions appropriate to my context. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally called "Code Analysis" and can come in various forms:

- Runtime code analysis (analyzing stack traces or exception unwinding)
- Static (source) code analysis (analyze source code or abstract syntax trees)
- Classification (big-O notation, algorithm classification, etc)

Recent versions of the **.NET Framework** have a rich compiler and code analysis framework known as the **.NET Compiler Platform**, often referred to as **Roslyn**, that makes it easier to analyze source code, and even integrate these analyses into **Visual Studio** via **Quick Fix** context menu, refactoring, compiler warnings, debugger visualizations, etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019